# Cannot use useState or useEffect in react what else do I have?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm in a position where I cannot use useState or useEffect in react. If I use useState it triggers infinite renders I cannot use useEffect because I need state to do something.

Example:

```
export default function MyApp(props) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const renderBody = (index) => {
        var temp = [];
        temp.push(props.data.results[index].correct_answer);
        props.data.results[index].incorrect_answers.forEach((current) => temp.push(current));
        var arr = shuffle(temp);   // shuffle is a function that shuffles array elements I need to shuffle only once but this shuffles elements every render
        setOptions(options => arr);  // this triggers infinite render I need this to be in useEffect(() => {}, [])
        return (<div>{arr.map((value) => { <p>{value}</p> })}</div>);
}
    return (
        <div className="main"> 
            {props.data.results.map((value, index) => {
                {renderBody(index)}
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Because the renderBody function takes a parameter "index" I cannot use useEffect directly because I don't think so that useEffect takes a parameter
So what can I do?, Is there's a react hook that I'm not aware of?, Is there a react library that solves this problem?

Comment: I'm building a Quiz game and the rendeBody function displays options for a quiz

Comment: i've simplified things here a bit if you want to check out full code go here:https://gist.github.com/JunedKhan101/d86cab022fd1858e21c64a37b5c9eab7

Comment: the props that my component receives is "data" from a Quiz component

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you are trying to achieve and what's the problem is. So that we can help you. *Infinite renders in your case are because of updating the state in the render*

Comment: i don't know what you need but you can check out full code in repo: https://github.com/JunedKhan101/Quiz-game

Comment: @Emilia-tan your requirement is quite confusing, please explain it in detail

Comment: Let me try to explain: I'm building a Quiz game, i received data from an api that I have not shown for the sake of simplicity, I have to set the options for the every quiz question as xyou can see in the renderBody function the api gives me data in an array (data.results) every result has a question (a string), a correct answer (a string) and an array of incorrect answers now If I always fetch correct answer first and then all the incorrect answers then it would not be good if the correct answer is always render first in a Radio group so I'm shuffling them,

Comment: but I don't want to shuffle at every render I want to shuffle only once that is the problem I have if you need to do something only once you use `useEffect(() => {}, [])` but it doesn't work because I cannot set state in while rendering and hence i cannot set options for a quiz question in useEffect. So The point is How can I set options for a quiz question only once not every render?

Comment: If I don't shuffle the array of options and just render arbitrarily, then anyone can figure out that the first option is always the correct one

Comment: @Nithish  If I can't update the state in render then what do I do?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Please check my comments I've tried to explain my best

Comment: If you want your code to only run once, move it outside of the `renderBody` function and put it inside a useEffect with an empty dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect can handle that, you need to pass the state you want to check the changes in an array as the second parameter of useEffect

```
export default function MyApp(props) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    useEffect(function(){
        //this execute once the props.data changes
    },[props.data]);
}
    return (
        <div className="main"> 
            {options.map((value, index) => {
                /*make sure you include the index in an element*/
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

What happen is;

- Once your application load, and the component has no data, options is set to an empty array. So the map function does not loop once.
- The data is loaded from the parent component. Triggering the useEffect hook, reloading the component (and running the useEffect, you set the new state of options here)
- The map functions loops trought the now set options state

Comment: If props.data is not changing then this useEffect get called only once am i correct?

Comment: Well ultimately the component is loading twice because props.data IS changing, because you assign it from the parent component.

Comment: But this doesn't work as the useEffect needs access to index

Comment: What do you mean, what is this index you are talking about? the index of your values? or is it in a state?

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
  var temp = [];
  temp.push(props.data.results[index].correct_answer);
  props.data.results[index].incorrect_answers.forEach((current) => temp.push(current));
  var arr = shuffle(temp);
  setOptions(options => arr);
 }, [props.data]);` index is undefined obviously

Comment: I need access to index set options

Comment: `var temp=[];
props.data.results.map(function(value,index){
  //looping throught the result
 console.log(value);
});`

Map does a great job at this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229233/discussion-between-emilia-tan-and-danys-chalifour).